# How to show a Toast using a RunOnUIThread method

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to figure out why the toast is not showing. from the code, the onReceive method does get executed and change the button color, but the Toast does not display. I dont  know why.

```
 client = new Client(
                (publisher, topic, params) -> runOnUiThread(
                        () -> onReceive((Publisher) publisher, topic, params)
                ));

            client.connectToServer("192.168.3.52",5050);

  private void onReceive(Publisher publisher, String topic, Map<String, Object> params) {


        sendBtn.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.white));

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hey", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Imports

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Class name

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: The issue is not with thread because in that case your button backgroundColor would also have not chagne

Comment: @AshutoshOjha , toasts that are outside that method do show, that why i am thinking runonuithread is the problem

Comment: Have you  tried using debugger ?  Is app control coming to the Toast ?

Comment: I changed the emulator and the android version. Now its showing

Answer (score 0):

hey can you share your file name and import section ........
or else try to run on clicklistener after **sendbtn** and try to link with your button

Comment: Still not working, I have shared the imports

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).